# How to trigger intellij to update MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij. I have a Java web application and there is a MANIFEST.MF file under the src/main/webapp/META-INF directory, sometimes I notice that this file is updated (not sure if it is when I import the project or when I build the module) by something (not me, I am assuming it is Intellij), but the entries in the MANIFEST.MF file is not correct, the jars in the Class-Path are not up-to-date (not the ones that I defined in the pom.xml file, the versions of the jars are the old versions, maybe I had the old versions before, but they are all changed to newer version in pom.xml already).

My question is, since Intellij is updating the MANIFEST.MF during some process, how can I trigger that explicitly and force Intellij to update that file, there must be a way, right? (So far I have tried Intellij build module, maven build, maven reimport, removing the entries in the MANIFEST.MF file but nothing seems to work)

Note: this question is not about war file generation.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you for replying, this link seems not related to my question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I do have an artifact, and I am able to locally run my application in Jboss as well. in the Run/Debug Configurations, I have to tasks before launch: Build and Build 'myApp:war' artifact.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried build artifact as well, but the link you mentioned is about how to update deployed artifact (from the already changed classes or resources BY YOU), but my question is about how to force Intellij to update the MANIFEST.MF file in the src fold FOR YOU. similar to Intellij updating .iml file, it should happen automatically.

Comment: Try to delete the artifacts and reimport the Maven project. It should create the artifacts again and update the manifest.

Comment: That also tried, not solving the problem. The things is I don't even know when Intellij will update Menifest file, it is for sure doing that, because I do see sometimes that file got changed, but not correctly, for example I have a dependency abc.jar:1.1 in pom.xml, and this jar entry is in the manifest, later I change the version to abc.jar:1.2 in pom.xml, sometimes (not always, that's my question) Intellij will update the manifest to have both entries (wrong), or keep just the old version (also wrong), the correct way is it should just have the 1.2 version and remove the 1.1 version.

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project to reproduce.